# how to include SVG Sprite into component?

Tags: html, angular, svg

my normal html looks like:

```
<svg class="user-nav__icon">
        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-chat"></use>
</svg>
```

the svg path: ''assets/img/sprite.svg#icon-chat''

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to add a sprite with the icons in the `HTML` page:

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/sprite.svg">
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>`

- Then you can use the icons from this sprite in different places
  `HTML`. The size of the icons can be changed or left, as is, with the
  help of `viewBox`

```html
<svg class="user-nav__icon" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-chat"></use>
</svg> 

<svg class="user-nav__icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-user"></use>
</svg>
```